# Resuming automation after a CAPTCHA has been completed

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm currently writing a program (puppeteer and node.js) that can autonavigate and autofill user data on a specific website. The user is prompted with a CAPTCHA at a certain point, but I'm not sure how to signal to the program that the CAPTCHA has been completed after the fact so that it can resume it's processes.

Right now, the end of my fairly linear processes is

```
    await page.type('#orcer.string.required', cvv);
    page.waitFor(50);
    await page.click('input.button')
```

When that last line executes, the CAPTCHA instance is created. Is there a specific function in puppeteer that will allow the program to resume after the user fills it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way: how does a human user operating browser understand that work may be resumed after captcha is completed?

Some element, like captcha placeholder, is gone or some other element has appeared. Therefore you can use [page.waitFor](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) or [page.waitForFunction](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-options-args) to observe the page for those changes.

```
await page.type('#orcer.string.required', cvv);
page.waitFor(50);
await page.click('input.button') 
await pageWaitFor('.element-shown-after-captcha-solved')
```

You should also probably disable or set very high [timeouts](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaulttimeouttimeout) so that script doesn't throw error because of long waiting.

Comment: if once the captcha is solved it navigates to a new webpage would I just want to detect an element on that new webpage?

Comment: in that case you could also use `waitForNavigation` method to wait while a new page is loaded